# Vibration or shudder on Honda CRV

Tags: honda, steering, vibration, crv

My Honda CRV 2013 (just over 100000kms on the clock) has developed a shudder or vibration that is giving very prevelant and annoying feedback on the steering wheel and also when accelerating.  It started out very faint back in Feb of this year and now it has deteriorated that I can feel it at all speeds but especially at speeds exceeding 120km/h when it becomes almost undriveable.  Honda South Africa has replaced so many parts it may sound like a fairytale, eg drive shaft, gear box, front shocks, etc.  Then recently they claim it must be the wheels themselves ie rims and tyres.  I obtained three other expert opinions stating by inspection it's not the rims, so before I replace my now 50000 km old tyres I wanted to just check with you as well perhaps.  We just returned from a holiday and I must admit that there is quite a hollow wobbly type sound eminating from the Cross Continental tyres (not sure if front or back though) so it may just be those. I really cannot afford to replace rims and tyres and I'd hate to be disappointed again.